# How can python psycopg2 ignore some internal error when commit many queries

Tags: python, commit, psycopg2, rollback

I got some trouble when using python psycopg2 commit some queries, below is my code:

```
db = psycopg2.connect(database="**", user="**", password="**", host="**", port="**")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("***") # actually I have many cursor.execute()
db.commit()
```

my problem is when commit so many queries, if it occurs some error within some of them, the whole commit program will dead, and how could I ignore these error and commit the rest of the queries?

I have try to do something:

```
db = psycopg2.connect(database="**", user="**", password="**", host="**", port="**")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("***") # many cursor.execute()
for i in range(3):
    try:
        db.commit()
        break
    except Exception, e:
        db.rollback()
        log.write(traceback.format_exc() + "\n\n sql error: " + e.pgerror)
        time.sleep(1.5)
```

But it seems not work, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do without transaction, using `db.autocommit = True`. Alternatively you can use the `SAVEPOINT` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` sql statements.

Comment: autocommit = True seems to solve my problem perfectly, http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html Here give some details about my problem.  Thanks a billion!

Answer (score 1):

would you not do the following instead?

```
db = psycopg2.connect(database="**", user="**", password="**", host="**", port="**")
cursor = db.cursor()
for i in range(3):
    try:
        cursor.execute("***")
    except Exception, e:
        db.rollback()
    else:
        db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it again.